# Mostrar texto com a 1º letra maiúscula

Tags: php

Eu gostaria de saber como mostrar dados da *database*, que estes comecem todos com a primeira letra em maiúsculo, exemplo *"Eu sou bom"*, e não *"eu sou bom"*.

Existe alguma forma de o fazer?

Answer (score 7):

sim, use [ucfirst](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ucfirst.php)

```
ucfirst("eu sou bom"); //Retorna "Eu sou bom"
```

Comment: agradecido!!!!!

Comment: @user106225 clique na setinha verde abaixo das setas de votar para considerar a resposta como correta.